# How to play a gltf animation in reverse if intersects is not true. Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I have been working on implementing a gltf model into a three js project and would like to know if there is any way to reverse a gltf animation when the mouse hovers away from the gltf model. So far I have been able to get the gltf model to play its animation as the mouse hovers over the model, but I would like to reverse the animation once the mouse leaves the model. If anyone could please give me some insight on how I might go about this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'; 
import { GLTFLoader } from 'GLTFLoader';
import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

// Load 3D Scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

// Load Camera Perspective
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 25, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight );
camera.position.set( 10, 1, 25 );

// Load a Renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false });
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Load the Orbitcontroller
var controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

// Load Light
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF );
scene.add( ambientLight );

// Load gltf model and play animation
var mixer;
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(1, 1);
var loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load( './assets/itc.glb', function ( gltf ) {
var object = gltf.scene;
scene.add( object );
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
var action;
gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
    action = mixer.clipAction(clip);
    action.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
    action.clampWhenFinished = true;
    action.play();
});


object.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );
object.rotation.y = 37.0;
object.position.x = -10;                  //Position (x = right+ left-)
object.position.y = -5;                 //Position (y = up+, down-)
object.position.z = -15;                  //Position (z = front +, back-)

});


// Animate function
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    raycaster.setFromCamera( pointer, camera );

    const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    if (intersects.length){
      mixer.update(clock.getDelta());
    }
    else{
      // How can i reverse the animation when mouse pointer leaves the gltf model
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

// Render function
function render() {
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

// On window resize
var tanFOV = Math.tan( ( ( Math.PI / 180 ) * camera.fov / 2 ) );
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
function onWindowResize( event ) {
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
// adjust the FOV
camera.fov = ( 360 / Math.PI ) * Math.atan( tanFOV * ( 
window.innerHeight / windowHeight ) );
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onPointerMove( event ) {
    pointer.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}


window.addEventListener( 'pointermove', onPointerMove );

render();
animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to reverse an animation is to set the [timeScale](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.timeScale) property to `- 1`. So in your case:

```js
action.timeScale = - 1;
```

You can update the `timeScale` property at any point in your code.